# I want to write a function that takes a list and returns a count of total number of duplicate elements in the list

Tags: python

I have tried this, for some unknown reason when it prints h, it prints None, so i thought if it counts the number of None printed then divided by 2 it will give the number of duplicates, but i cant use function count here

```
a= [1,4,"hii",2,4,"hello","hii"]
def duplicate(L):
    li=[]
    lii=[]
    h=""
    for i in L:
        y= L.count(i)
        if y>1:
            h=y
            print h
            print h.count(None)

duplicate(a)
```

Comment: This is what `collections.Counter` is for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Counter` container:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(['a', 'b', 'a'])
```

`c` is now a dictionary with the data: `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})`

If you want to get a list with all duplicated elements (with no repetition), you can do as follows:

```
duplicates = filter(lambda k: c[k] > 1, c.iterkeys())
```

If you want to only count the duplicates, you can then just set

```
duplicates_len = len(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` to get the count of unique elements, and then compare the sizes - something like that:

```
def duplicates(l):
    uniques = set(l)
    return len(l) - len(uniques)
```

Comment: Beware, if you use this code will only be correct if the elements appear at most twice in the list. For example, if `l = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3]` you will get `4` but you only have 2 elements that are repeated.

Answer (score -1):

the answer by egualo is much better, but here is another way using a dictionary.

```
def find_duplicates(arr):
    duplicates = {}
    duplicate_elements = []

    for element in arr:
        if element not in duplicates:
            duplicates[element] = False
        else:
            if duplicates[element] == False:
                duplicate_elements.append(element)
            duplicates[element] = True

        return duplicate_elements
```

It's pretty simple and doesn't go through the lists twice which is kind of nice.

```
>> test = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,4]
>> find_duplicates(test)
[1, 2]
```

Comment: This requires the elements in the list to be hashable to be able to use them as keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

i found an answer which is

```
a= [1,4,"hii",2,4,"hello",7,"hii"]
def duplicate(L):
    li=[]
    for i in L:
        y= L.count(i)
        if y>1:
            li.append(i)
    print len(li)/2

duplicate(a)
```